# 英数字と日本語のフォントを別々に指定することは可能ですか？

Tags: emeditor

例えば、日本語の文章の中に英単語や数字が混ざっていた場合、日本語のフォントは「MSゴシック」、英数字の部分だけ「Consolas」にすることは可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [テキスト レンダリング] ページで、[DirectWirteを使用する] が設定されていることを確認して、下の [フォールバック フォント] 一覧の右の [追加] ボタンをクリックして、MSゴシックを選択しておきます。そして、現在の設定のプロパティの [表示] ページ - [フォント] ボタンで、Consolas を選択しておけば、Consolasで表示できる範囲の英数字はConsolasで表示され、日本語はMSゴシックで表示されます。

[image: EmEditor - カスタマイズ - テキスト レンダリング]

Comment: ありがとうございます。望み通りの結果を得ることができました。大変助かりました。